# Can't use mkdir unless sudo is used

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, samba, permissions

I lost my ssd on my pi and had to buy a new one, when installing the lite version of the OS I used the imager tool to create a "pi" user, since it does not do it automatically anymore. But now I can't use mkdir /usb, it says access denied.

"pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mkdir /usb
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usb’: Permission denied"

I can do it using it sudo mkdir /usb but when I did so I could not get samba permissions on the directory from my Windows machine. Here is the smb.conf:

`[HomePi] path = /mnt/usb/Media writeable = yes create mask = 0777 directory mask = 0777 public = no`

Answer (score 1):

To create a new directory/folder using `mkdir`, you must have the *permissions* set by the parent directory/folder. Since you are attempting to create `/usb`, you must have `root` permissions because `/` is not only the parent directory, it is also owned by `root`.

You may create and use `/usb` with `sudo`, but you may be overlooking another directory already created for the purpose of mounting external drives: `/mnt`. The advantage of using `mnt` over a directory that you create is that `mnt` is where externally mounted drives are *expected* to be found by some utilities and software.

Wrt `samba` permissions, recall that `samba` cannot override the permissions set in your file system. To avoid a mess, you should do something like this:

```bash
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/myusbdrive
$ sudo chown pi:pi /mnt/myusbdrive 
$ chmod <???> /mnt/myusbdrive  # where <???> are the file system permissions needed to support your Samba permissions; e.g. `744`
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure WHY you would WANT to create such a directory but any under / require root permission.

The pi user had/has passwordless sudo permission but any user (except root) on any Linux OS needs sudo.

Comment: I'm just a simple user trying to make a media center of a raspberry pi with tutorials I found online. I just would like to create a place for my media and my docker containers, where do you suggest me to create this folders?

Comment: @RafaelCarvalho If you have a Question you should ASK it - not something else. DO NOT ask in comments! This is a basic Linux question - not Pi specific, but any question needs to explain **what you hope to achieve**. Creating a directory ANYWHERE but your HOME needs `sudo`. Creating a new root directory seems like a BAD idea - I would question the tutorial.